# getting group information from Claimsidentity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

Im using azure active directory and I have users in 2 groups, when a user logs into my app (mvc5 & c#) I want to be able to determine what groups they belong to. How do I do this ?  I've tried

```
 ClaimsIdentity userClaimsId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var groups = userClaimsId.FindAll(ClaimTypes.GroupSid);
        var g = userClaimsId.Claims.Select(x => x.Type.Equals("groups")).ToList();
```

but it doesn't work.  Id eventually like to create an attribute to decorate controller methods as well as possibly an extension method.  But in the meantime Id like to be able to see the groups in the ClaimsIdentity.  Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the end, just bad linq :-(

```
var g2 = userClaimsId.Claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals("groups")).ToList();
```

Comment: How to get the group name from the object g2 above?

Comment: Are you able to get group name from this? @NAGARAJAHI